# How to "force the WiX .exes to run out-of-process"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, wix, votive

There is a bug in the [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) plugin for Visual Studio where file locks on referenced DLLs are not properly released. Therefore, you have to restart Visual Studio every time you want to recompile a custom extension DLL or any assembly referenced by it.

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4034), but the issue was closed because there seems to be a solution / workaround:

> You can force the WiX .exes to run out-of-process to avoid the lock
>   MSBuild has.

I don't understand how to achieve this. I checked...

- the properties of my WiX setup project
- the properties of the extension assembly (C# class library)
- all Visual Studio settings
- the available command line arguments of candle.exe

...but did not find anything. What am I missing? How do I apply this workaround?

I'm using WiX 3.10 and Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example that I've seen several times around the web is to add `<RunWixToolsOutOfProc>true</RunWixToolsOutOfProc>` to the Wix Installer's project file within a property group. Unfortunately, documentation of this feature has thus far eluded me.

Comment: If you have a similar problem with the MsBuild tasks such as `<HeatDirectory>`, adding the `RunAsSeparateProcess="true"` attribute to the Wix Tool element for whatever tool you wish to enable this for, will work.